# can't find free space and windows 10 while installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

i have been trying and installing Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot along with windows 10 . i have created free space which is from basic MBR (NTFS) . but whenever i'm gonna install Ubuntu , it's says in the middle of the installation that "this computer currently has no detected operating systems" and couldn't able to find any free space or any unallocated drive . i have tried many times with different solution but can't able to find and install that . Is there anyone can help me out with proper info . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why MBR? Is your windows installed in Legacy BIOS boot mode? Does your PC support UEFI boot mode? You have to make sure that you boot into the Ubuntu USB using the same boot mode...

Comment: Make sure Win10 fast boot option is off.  If it is MBR then it can only have four primary partitions.  Should also use the 'Something Else' option for installing.

Comment: Yes,  it is in legacy bios boot mode.  I didn’t try UEFI boot mode.  I used same boot mode 

Comment: @crip659 yeah fast boot option is off.  And it has four partitions.  Still its says that ”it can't find windows 10"

Comment: Is the Ubuntu install seeing the drive, but not partitions or not seeing the drive at all?

Comment: Ubuntu install seeing /dev/sta.  Nothing else 

Comment: Think Win10 is using dynamic partition instead of a regular partition, but this is more than I can help with.  Use Try Ubuntu on installer and see what gparted can see.

Comment: @crip659 not dynamic,  it’s basic partition.  Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @Md.JahidulIslam Does your PC support UEFI? IF so you better convert windows to UEFI. You can use the MBR2GPT utility inbuilt in windows. See this. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10